# Programa en python para eliminar vocales de una frase

Tags: python

he estado creando un programa para eliminar las vocales de una palabras ingresada desde el teclado.

Este es el Código, no se si me hace falta algo, al ingresar la palabras, solo se detiene el programa y ya. help me please...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Por otro lado, edita la pregunta y agrega el código como texto, de este modo aumentas las chances que cualquier usuario pueda copiar/pegar, reproducir tu escenario y ayudarte con algo de código. Saludos.

Comment: No necesitas convertir el valor de retorno de `input` a `string`. Según la [documentación de `input`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#input) siempre devuelve un objeto string.

Comment: Tu variable `vowels` es una [`tupla`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). `letter` siempre es una string. Por lo tanto nunca será cierta la expresión `letter == vowels`. Para comprobar que `letter` esté presente en `vowels` debes hacer `if letter in vowels`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí hay varias cosas que tratar, pero el principal problema por el que no te funciona, está aquí:

```
for letter in phrase:
    if letter == vowels: <- aquí 
       phrase = phrase.replace(vowels, "")
       print(phrase)
```

El bucle for es un bloque de código que se ejecuta una vez por cada elemento de un iterable (una lista o una tupla). En este caso, se ejecuta entero, por cada letter dentro de phrase.

El condicional if, compara vowels, que es una tupla que contiene carácteres, y letter es un carácter, por lo que la igualdad no se cumple y no se ejecuta el bloque if.

Y aunque se puede ir carácter a carácter, guardarlos en una lista y convertir esa lista en un string, creo que es bastante más fácil de la siguiente forma:

```
for letter in vowels:
    phrase = phrase.replace(letter, "")

print(phrase)
```

Ahora el bucle lo que hace es, coger cada letra de la lista vowels, mirar si está dentro de phrase, sustituirla por nada (eliminarla) y guardar el resultado en la variable phrase.

PS: El print lo he puesto fuera del bucle para que vieras el resultado, si quieres ver el resultado de cada ejecución del bucle, ponlo dentro.

Comment: Holaaa, muchisimas graciass por tu respuesta. Pude aclarar los conceptos que tenia de los bucles y el condicional if. Creo que fue muy claro y pude entender, aun llevo poco aprendiendo y entrando a este mundo y realmente te agradezco por tu ayuda.